# Openlayers pan/zoom on windows 8 app

Tags: openlayers-2, windows-8

I'm building a windows 8 js application with an Iframe that uses openlayers with google as the basemap. Everything is working except for the map navigation. When I try to pan or zoom with my finger, the whole page moves, not the map. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to add the style -ms-touch-action: none to the frame that the map was in. That made the frame stop moving and the map start moving.